# What is the memory map of a w65c02s?

Tags: microprocessor

What is the memory map of w65c02s?

The datasheet is not clear at all compared to the atmega328p.

Can someone put up a chart and explain the memory space of this microprocessor?

Comment: Assuming this is still some species of 6502, it's whatever you make it. But you'd better ensure there's RAM in the bottom 256 bytes, that's what it uses instead of a register file.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Re the register file: not entirely. The 65(C)02 does have a limited set of registers of its own but many of its most useful addressing modes make use of the first 256 bytes of RAM (called zero page). This is not commonly referred to as a register file but it has many of the aspects of one. The 65(C)02 also has a fixed stack at memory locations 0x100-0x1ff (growing down from 0x1ff). FWIW the 65c02 is still being manufactured.

Comment: @StarCat that's why I didn't call page 0 a register file. But I had no idea the stack model was so restrictive, I was firmly in the other camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6502 was designed for a minimal system with an external 2316 ROM or 2716 ERPOM and the 6532 companion chip. That one had RAM, Timers and GPIO. You had to invent some glue logic from 74xx and/or 40xx chips yourself. That glue logic decided on the address map.

You could in fact have the reset vector hardwired to some mechanical hex switch with the glue logic mapping it to adresses 0xfffc and 0xfffd and I pretty much guess this was implemented more than once for debugging purposes.

Those two addresses are the only ones which you really need to decode as stated in the datasheet. All other address mappings you can either ignore (and lose their special function) or you set them up with the glue logic as you see it fit.

Apart from the Reset, NMI, and IRQ vectors at the end of the address map, the 0x0000 to 0x00ff range is special to the 6502 as it can be accessed by two-byte instructions and you can use it as a parameter stack through the (offset,X) addressing mode, and the 0x0100 to 0x01ff range is special to the 6502 as it is intended as the subroutine return stack.

A minimal system with the above chips will most likely have the glue logic arrange 0x0000–0x003f as RAM (variables and parameter stack), 0x0080–0x009f as I/O, 0x0100-0x013f as RAM (return stack), and 0xf800–0xffff as ROM. If you need more RAM or I/O, you can easily add another 6532 and map that one at 0x0040-0x007f, 0x00c0-0x00df, 0x0140-0x17f.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the memory map of 65c02w?

Well, "vestigial" would be a misnomer, because that implies that it had one to begin with.  "Mostly up to you" would be a better way to put it.

> The datasheet is not clear at all compared to the atmega328p.

From the perspective of a modern micro**controller** like the atmega328p, a first-generation micro**processor** like the 6502 is just a core.  There's a bit of memory that must be populated (see Brian Drummand's comment), there's a few fixed locations for interrupt and reset vectors -- and that's it.  It's up to the board designer to provide I/O, make sure there's flash that covers those vectors at $FFxx and RAM at $0000-$001FF.  Beyond that -- whatever you design in, that's what you get.

Most of the early microprocessors were designed to have RAM at one end of the memory space and ROM at the other -- this one would have been RAM at $0000 up, and ROM at $FFFF down.  If they didn't provide a specific I/O bus like the Z-80 (and, I think, the 8080) then you'd use memory-mapped I/O in the middle.

But it was very much up to you -- a "microcontroller" like the current crop of AT-Mega chips would be realized by a board six inches on a side, but with the peripherals hard-wired and with many fewer of them.